# Exact way of glmnet computing best lambda

Tags: r, regression, python, cross-validation, glmnet

I'm doing some research and want to get the best lambda with cross validation in python.
For my dataset the R! package glmnet works pretty well, but I can not find out how it's implemented.
There are so many parameters and even in the source code I can't find any lines where they perform CV.
Does anyone know which approach they use?

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/4.0-2/topics/glmnet

I have found out that in default case they use 10 folds und also do standardization. Which kind of standardization?
I would be very thankful if anyone can give me some more hints how they compute their lambda values.

Answer (score 2):

Recommend viewing their tutorial here:

- https://glmnet.stanford.edu/articles/glmnet.html

You will see that the function call you are looking for for getting the optimal $\lambda$ that minimizes the mean cross-validated error is `cvmfit$lambda.min` where `lambda` is a sequence of $\lambda$s. This means they are merely doing a grid-search, by solving the `glmnet` model for a sequence of $\lambda$s, and pin-pointing the minimum on that curve.

`glmnet` standardizes $y$ to have unit variance before computing its lambda sequence, also discussed in the tutorial.